Return first n characters following header in fasta file
I'm trying to extract the first n sequences following a header in a fasta file. Headers are defined typically with a ">" character, such that a block of sequences corresponding to a specific header looks as follows:
>chr1
ATCGATCG
>chr2
TCAGACT

Given this, I'm trying to extract say the first three sequences following a header (these sequences are usually millions of Bp). For example my desired output would be:
ATC
TCA

Returned line by line to stdout, such that if there are 60 headers there should be 60 sequences returned of length 3. Here's what I have tried so far:
grep -o -E "[A-Z]\w+" *.fasta | cut -c -3

The problem is this returns the first 3 sequences of every line rather than those just following a header.
What I'm thinking is something like this:
grep -o -E "^>+\n+[A-Z]\w+" *.fasta | cut -c -3

But this returns nothing, any thoughts?

Try sed -nE '/^>/{n;s/^(.{3}).*/\1/p}' fasta_file_here

Or, awk '/^>/{next} {print substr($0, 1, 3)}' fast_file_here

@WiktorStribiżew Didn't seem to work, both approaches return the same output as my first grep approach. Inspecting my fasta, it looks like the sequences are wrapped at 60bp, so every 60bp there is a line break. I think this might be one of the problems

@WiktorStribiżew Ok I think I got it, making the fasta linear first then piping the awk command gives me what I need: cat *.fasta | awk '{if (substr($0,1,1) == ">") {if (p) {print "\n";} print $0} else printf("%s",$0);p++;}END{print "\n"}' | awk '/^>/{next} {print substr($0,1,8)}'

Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases. Note that fasta format allows multiline sequences. For this task, I recommend EMBOSS utility called seqret.

Use seqret utility from the EMBOSS package:
seqret -filter in.fasta -sbegin 1 -send 3 | grep -v '^>' > out.txt

cat out.txt
ATC
TCA

Use conda to install EMBOSS or many other common bioinformatics packages. For example:
conda install --channel bioconda emboss

or, better, install into a separate environment:
conda create --channel bioconda --name emboss emboss

and activate this environment later like so:
conda activate emboss


I will give this package a try, didn't know about it thank you!
