linux - sed command to search a substring in a file, then modify that a substring in that line only and keep the lines in the file
With linux the sed command is it possible to do a sed command to search a substring in a file, then modify that a substring in that line only and keep the lines in the file, in one command line?
example file test.txt
foo bar
goo bar

I tried the following but it only saves the line affected not the whole file.
sed -in '/foo/{s/bar/bah/;p}' test.txt

Is it possible to do this in one sed command?

You were close. sed -i.bak '/foo/s/bar/bah/' input_file

@sseLtaH That should be an answer, not a comment.

The -n sed option is a filtering mechanism, such that the programmer may choose to explicitly print (p) or not print (do nothing) a line. Since in this case the OP wants to print every line it is not needed and the default mechanism (not using the -n option)  will work just fine. However the OP could effect the same by printing every line explicitly e.g sed -n '/foo/s/bar/bah/;p' file

As above, "less is more" (-;

This is a task for awk because it's cleaner, more hardened and easier to maintain:
awk '$1=="foo"{sub("bar", "bah", $2)} 1' file 

to edit in place, you can use sponge:
awk ...... file | sponge file

or use -i inplace (require GNU awk).
To decompose a bit:
This is the awk basics:
condition{action}

so



Pseudo code
awk code




if
$1=="foo" first column == foo


then
{sub("bar", "bah", $2)} substitution with sub() on the second column


finally
1 implicit print on a true condition (1 is true)




Whether you feel sed or awk are easier to maintain depends on which one you know better. For the uninitiated, either one looks like line noise. The question asked about a sed solution. An awk alternative should be a comment at best.

Yes, like questions that ask sed to edit HTML :D The force of a Q/A website is to point ppl in a better way when possible.

I've always avoided awk because mainly I don't know what I'm doing with it. But thanks for the answer too.

@DevSolar when people ask for a sed solution it's almost always because sed is the only tool they are familiar with but actually are happy with the best solution using commonly available Unix tools. The only time they NEED a sed solution is when it's a homework question specifically about sed. It's like if someone asks how to cut down a tree using a hammer when they have an axe in their toolbelt - suggesting they use their axe instead would almost certainly be a useful answer.

@Langerz if you're going to be doing any text processing in a Unix environment you should consider awk for the job. grep is great for simple g/re/p operations, sed is great for simple s/old/new/ operations but for anything more complicated than that an awk solution will be some combination of simpler, clearer, more robust, more efficient and more portable than grep or sed or any combination of them.

You can get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk but it's basically a tiny subset of C wrapped in an implicit while-read loop that does the usual necessary text processing operations such as splitting each input line into fields for you so once you understand THAT part it becomes extremely easy to use and it's a mandatory POSIX tool (unlike perl, python, ruby, etc.) so it's available on all Unix boxes, just like grep and sed.

As an example of robustness (if I understand your requirements) - the awk solution in this answer will work even if foo appears in an undesirable location in the input or if foo actually contains regexp metachars or if foo can appear as a substring of another string in the expected location or if bar can appear in an undesirable location or as a substring while the sed solution in the comments, /foo/s/bar/bah/ would fail in all cases.

Why was it downvoted unfairly ?

Dunno, but feel free to push up ^^

Yeah I upvoted first then commented

@EdMorton Whether this awk solution is in any way better than a proper sed one is firmly in the eye of the beholder.

You don't say it but, since you're using -n with -p, your script appears to be trying to remove all lines that do not contain foo as well as modify the 2nd field so I think this is probably what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for -i inplace, just like you were using GNU sed for -i:
awk -i inplace '$1=="foo"{ if ($2=="bar") $2="bah"; print }' test.txt

For example:
$ cat test.txt
foo bar
goo bar


$ awk -i inplace '$1=="foo"{ if ($2=="bar") $2="bah"; print }' test.txt


$ cat test.txt
foo bah

You should test whatever solution you get with sample input that covers not just the sunny-day cases. For example, consider this which has regexp metachars (.) in the search strings and a backreference metachar (&) in the replacement and in all cases they should be considered literal and full field matches (see How do I find the text that matches a pattern?):
$ cat test.txt
f.o b.r
foo bar
f.o bxr
f.o xb.r
xf.o b.r
f.obar b.r
b.r f.o


$ awk '$1=="f.o"{ if ($2=="b.r") $2="b&h"; print }' test.txt
f.o b&h
f.o bxr
f.o xb.r

Note that in each case you got the output where the first field exactly matched f.o and you changed the 2nd field only when it exactly matched b.r and it was changed to b&h.
Now lets try the sed solution from the comments, tweaked to only print lines that match the target string (foo in the question, f.o in this example):
$ sed -n '/f.o/{s/b.r/b&h/; p}' test.txt
f.o bb.rh
foo bb.rh
f.o bbxrh
f.o xbb.rh
xf.o bb.rh
f.obbarh b.r
bb.rh f.o

and note all the undesirable lines being output and incorrect replacements it made.

Why was it downvoted unfairly ?

@anubhava Several of my answers have been getting downvoted recently for no reason (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79095068/return-first-n-characters-following-header-in-fasta-file/79095467#79095467). Ah well, people need a hobby... :-).

There are some trigger happy people around

In my case because of the dig at an incomplete SED "solution" for "comparison", and the same reason I downvoted the other awk answer. Clarifying tue question (including whether another tool would be acceptable) is what Q comments are for.

@DevSolar there is no "dig" in the comparison. It's showing the differences between the suggested solutions given input the OP probably hasn't considered and anyone with a similar problem will almost certainly will have to face some day, that is all, You're being far to focused on getting a sed solution rather than the best (robust, clear, portable, extendable, etc.) solution using the available tools and not all clarifications can fit in or are best represented by a comment. It often takes an answer to help the OP understand the concerns.

The dig is that you introduced regexp characters to complicate the issue, then intentionally didn't escape them for sed to call your broken sed "solution" out on "incorrect" replacements. sed -n '/^f\.o\b/{s/\bb\.r\b/b\&h/; p}' does just fine for your case. Since the question is now closed with a questionable duplicate, arguing the case for clarifying the OP's needs or providing a sed solution actually solving the question is moot, though.
